# How to get image pixel coordinates in java, by pointing mouse to a specific point on image?

Tags: java

I have a java code in which I need to open an image in a frame and display pixel's coordinates by moving mouse over that pixel, just like MS Paint displays. Is it possible in java? If yes, which GUI component is to be used?

Comment: Try this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, its possible. you can try this code.

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
PointerInfo a = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
Point point = new Point(a.getLocation());
SwingUtilities.convertPointFromScreen(point, e.getComponent());
x=(int) point.getX();
y=(int) point.getY();
```

}

this is Get Mouse Position pixel coordinates relative to JFrame.

as this you can do it for jLable etc.

Comment: You know, you could just use 1. `e.getLocationOnScreen()` or 2. `e.getPoint` which will give the point within the context of the component that generated the event

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible in java?

Yes...

> If yes, which GUI component is to be used?

Pretty much anything that extends `Component`, but conventionally, `JComponent` or `JPanel` if you want to paint the image yourself or `JLabel` if you'd just prefer to display the image without a lot of fuss

Take a look at [How to Use Labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) and [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) for starters...

You should also consider taking a look at [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) and [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) for some other ideas/help